# Communication between a client and a Docker Container on other server

Tags: docker, containers, communication

I am currently looking for the possibility to communicate with a Docker container that is not running on my own device but on a remote server. I am also in the same network through a VPN. This server is running multiple Docker containers but I only want to communicate with one specific container. Currently it would be enough for me to get a ping response.

I can get to the information of the container with`docker network ls` and `docker network inspect ...`.
So I can find the IP of the container (172.17.XXX.XXX). But when I try to ping it, I get the response from a different IP address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx):

```
Ping is executed for 172.17.XXX.XXX with 32 bytes of data:
    Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Destination network not reachable.
    Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Destination network not reachable.
    Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Destination network not reachable.
    Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Destination network not reachable.
```

Comment: You'd interact with this in the exact same way as if neither program was running in a container; via the remote host's DNS name and the `docker run -p` published port.  The `docker inspect` IP address is totally useless in this situation (and many others) and I wouldn't recommend looking it up.